# Cómo poner un audio personalizado y retrasar la alarma en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

estoy creando una alarma y tengo un problema cuando añado `.setSound()` este no funciona.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué no funciona? Además me gustaría que cuando llegue la hora este invoque una activity llamada `stop_alarm` para parar la alarma o para retrasarla y en tal caso, la app esté cerrada muestre una notificación o ejecute esa activity

Mi plan es que cuando se abra esta activity `stop_alarm` suene una cadena de sonidos personalizados y hasta que no se pare o se retrase estén en bucle un ejemplo en js seria

```
var sound = ["01.MP3","02.MP3"];
```

este es mi AlarmReceiver.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;

import static android.provider.Settings.System.getString;
import static com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers.TAG;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int soundResId = R.raw.cat;
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + soundResId);
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("todo");
        Uri notification = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.cat);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(), notification);
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 /* Request code */, mainIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
        String channelId = "channel-01";
        String channelName = "Alarm Notification";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                                      .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                                                      .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                                                      .build();

            mChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);




        }

        Bitmap largicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                                                      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
                                                      .setContentTitle("Ya es hora dormilon!")
                                                      .setContentText(message)
                                                      .setLargeIcon(largicon)
                                                      .setBadgeIconType(R.mipmap.ic_notification_round)
                                                      .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                                                      .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                      .setPriority(importance)

                                                      .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                                      .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                      .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);


        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT


        );

        //mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        //mBuilder.setSound(soundUri, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);



        //vibrate
        long[] v = {500,1000};
        mBuilder.setVibrate(v);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());



    }

}
```

aqui esta el apartado donde se configura la alarma

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class alarmset extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
private static final Object NOTIFICATION_NAME = "Alarm Notification";
private ImageView btncmenu;
private int notificationId = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarmset);

    // Set Onclick Listener.
    findViewById(R.id.setBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn).setOnClickListener(this);




    btncmenu = findViewById(R.id.menuclose);

    Animation trans = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.trans);
    btncmenu.startAnimation(trans);
    btncmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent m = new Intent(alarmset.this, menu.class);
            startActivity(m);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TimePicker timePicker = findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    // Set notificationId & text.
    Intent intent = new Intent(alarmset.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);
    intent.putExtra("todo", editText.getText().toString());

    // getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags)
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(alarmset.this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.setBtn:
            int hour = timePicker.getHour();
            int minute = timePicker.getMinute();

            // Create time.
            Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            long alarmStartTime = startTime.getTimeInMillis();

            // Set alarm.
            // set(type, milliseconds, intent)
            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime, alarmIntent);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Se Guardo la alarma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;

        case R.id.cancelBtn:
            alarm.cancel(alarmIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se cancelo la alarma.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }


}

}
```

y por último la activity `stop_alarm`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="446dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:translationY="300dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="229dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Parar alarma" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="179dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Aplazar" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Me gustaría que incluyeran código explicando cómo puedo realizar esto

Comment: Si bien veo el setSound que le aplicas al canal, este solo es efectivo si lo ejecutas desde un api superior creo que el O es el 23, si la app la estas testeando en uno inferior no te sonara, yo generalmente pongo tambien el setSound del NotificationCompat

Comment: uso la api de android Oreo en adelante, y la maxima api que uso es la de android 9 se supone que debería funcionar pero no corre el audio y tampoco se me ocurre como crear una activity para parar la alarma o retrasarla

Answer (score 1):

En donde está la línea   "notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());" indicas a la notificación que debe aparecer, por ello debes lanzar también el audio, lo puedes hacer con las dos líneas que añadí, suerte!

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int soundResId = R.raw.cat;
    Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + soundResId);
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("todo");
    Uri notification = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.cat);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(), notification);
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 /* Request code */, mainIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Alarm Notification";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                                  .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                                                  .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                                                  .build();



    }

    Bitmap largicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                                                  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
                                                  .setContentTitle("Ya es hora dormilon!")
                                                  .setContentText(message)
                                                  .setLargeIcon(largicon)
                                                  .setBadgeIconType(R.mipmap.ic_notification_round)
                                                  .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                                                  .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                  .setPriority(importance)

                                                  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                                  .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                  .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);


    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT


    );

    //mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    //mBuilder.setSound(soundUri, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);



    //vibrate
    long[] v = {500,1000};
    mBuilder.setVibrate(v);





    //Ya no uses este código, puede que no funcione en muchos dispositivos
        //mChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
       //Usa esto en cuanto hagas .notify para el receiver
       final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);

       //Llama al mp.start justo en el momento que llamas a notify
       mp.start();


    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());



}
```

Comment: y puedo pararlo desde otra activity?

Comment: claro que puedes, solo declara el MediaPlater como public estatic al inicio de la clase y desde otra activity escribe 
    TuServicio.mp.pause();

Comment: y para retrasar la alarma? como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: En realidad eso lo haces tú, tu le mandas cuando hacer ejecutar ese media player, pero para la pregunta que has posteado, es de esa manera.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando un MediaPlayer en el onClick que deseas:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
```

Después, dentro del onClick

```
mp.start();
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que MediaPlayer sigue funcionando desde muchos niveles de apis atras hasta las más actuales, te recomiendo hacer esto de manera nativa debido a que puede que tengas inconvenientes extras con .setSound()

Comment: hum interesante me podrías mostrar como Adaptar este código con el código que puse en mi pregunta

Comment: @UrielRamírez hay que evitar realizar más de una respuesta, realiza una basada en [ask], saludos.